# Use variable in ejs script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I want to use variable (or variables) in ejs file in the script tag ,I also want to pass the rendered file to a function for taking screenshot from ejs file.

But now I have 2 problems :

1.I don't know how to pass the variable in server file to the ejs file and render and use it without app.get... (in express) because it's server side and I want to use html file.

2.I don't know how to use variable in ejs file in the script tag

these are my files :

**index.ejs**

```
<div id="tvchart"><% symbol %></div>

<script>
//some codes 
 var symbolD =<%= symbol %>;
fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:9665/fetchAPI?endpoint=https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbolD}&interval=1m&limit=1000`)
</script>
```

**server.js**

```
// set the view engine to ejs
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
const symbol = "EGLDUSDT"

const file = ejs.render("./index.ejs" , symbol);
console.log(file)
```

So Why my ejs and server file doesn't work?

Comment: How to pass variables: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `render` needs to be an **object** where the property names are the variables passed to the EJS file.

```
ejs.render("./index.ejs" , {symbol});
```

Once you fix that `var symbolD =<%= symbol %>;` gives you `var symbolD =EGLDUSDT;` which throws an error because you don't have a variable named `EGLDUSDT`.

Use `JSON.stringify` to generate something compatible with JavaScript literal syntax (i.e. with quotes around strings and proper escaping for special characters).

```
var symbolD = <%= JSON.stringify(symbol) %>;
```